# Analytic proof that Lyapunov exponents in Hamiltonian systems pairwise sum to zero

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, chaos-theory, non-linear-systems, complex-systems

I have read that in Hamiltonian systems, [Lyapunov exponents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_exponent) come in pairs $(\lambda_i, \lambda_{2N-i+1})$ such that their sum is equal to zero.

Is there a way of proving this analytically?

EDIT: 
Saw this [here](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Lyapunov_exponent).

> In symplectic systems, LEs come in pairs $(\lambda_i, \lambda_{2N-i+1})$ such that their sum is equal to zero. This means that the Lyapunov spectrum is symmetric. It is a way of emphasizing the invariance of Hamiltonian dynamics under change of the time arrow.

Comment: Ah, I see. Still, you should a) give a reference for where you read that and b) show some research effort. Just typing "lyapunov exponents pair sum zero" into Google gives me [this paper](http://www.maths.bris.ac.uk/~macpd/old/proof.pdf) as a result, which even shows a generalization to non-Hamiltonian systems.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I agree. Since my own search is filled with stuff in context, I stepped over the need to provide one while asking on forum. Edited

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. We are considering a discrete time evolution $$x_{n}~=~f(x_{n-1})~=~f^{n\circ}(x_0), \qquad n~\in~\mathbb{N},$$ in a $2N$-dimensional [symplectic manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_manifold) $(M,\omega)$, where $f$ is a [symplectomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectomorphism).
2. Let us for simplicity work in local coordinates. Define the Jacobian matrix as
   $$\tag{1} A(x,n)^{i}{}_{j}~:=~\frac{\partial (f^{n\circ} (x))^i}{\partial x^j}. $$
3. In local [Darboux coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux's_theorem), the Jacobian matrix (1) is a [symplectic matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_matrix) 
   $$\tag{2}  A^T\Omega A~=~ \Omega, \qquad \Omega ~:=~\begin{bmatrix} 0_N & -I_N \cr I_N & 0_N \end{bmatrix}.$$
4. Note that the transposed $A^T$ is also a symplectic matrix. Note that $A^TA$ is a positive definite symplectic matrix.
5. *Symplectic quartet mechanism:* For a diagonalizable$^1$ symplectic matrix, the eigenvalues form quartets $$\tag{3} \{\lambda,\bar{\lambda}, \lambda^{-1},\bar{\lambda}^{-1}\}$$
   in the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$. 
   A quartet becomes a doublet on the real axis and on the unit circle.
6. Define the [Lyapunov exponents](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Lyapunov_exponent) $$\tag{4} \left\{\lambda_1(x,n), \ldots, \lambda_{2N}(x,n)\right\}~\subset~\mathbb{R} $$ as the eigenvalues of the Hermitian matrix
   $$\tag{5} \Lambda(x,n)~:=~\frac{1}{2n}\ln \left(A(x,n)^TA(x,n)\right).$$
7. It follows from the symplectic doublet mechanism (3), that the eigenvalues (4) are distributed symmetrically around 0 on the real axis $\mathbb{R}$.

--

$^1$Not all symplectic matrices are diagonalizable. 2D Counterexample: $$\tag{6} A~=~\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \cr 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: +1, Just a brief comment, since any continuous-time-translation is a symplectic transformation, then the continuous-time case is a trivial generalization. I also believe that the matrix $A^T A$ is positive semi-definite and thus will have exclusively $\lambda=\bar{\lambda}$ degenerate quartets.

Comment: @Void: I agree.